# How can I return a list of numbers from a given list that mod 0 a target number?

Tags: list, recursion, math, prolog, sublist

In my function modded(X,Y,Z), a list is generated based off of a given number Y and a given list of numbers Z. What I am trying to do is go through the list Z for each of its values and see if the current value in the list will cleanly divide Y, `(Y/Zz == 0)`. I am a bit confused on how to access each of Z's values since Prolog does not have traditional iterators.

Expected behavior would be for modded(X,16,[2,3,4,5,7,8]) to return a list of [2,4,8]. Only complete divisors are allowed.

```
modded([],Y,Z):-
    % X is the generated list, Y is the number, Z is a list of given numbers.
    %Base case: Z is empty
    Z =:= [],
    X =:= Z.

modded([Zz|T],Y,[H|T]):-
    %Recursive is Y > 1, Zz is an element of Z
    0 is Y mod Zz,
    Y =< Z - 1,
    Zz is Z + 1,
    % Want to add to a if Y mod Zz == 0
    modded(T,Y,Zz).
```

Comment: See: SWI-Prolog [convlist/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=convlist/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
modded([], _, []).

modded([Zz|T], Y, [Zz|Z]) :- % Case where Zz is a divisor of Y.
    0 =:= Y mod Zz,
    modded(T, Y, Z).

modded(T, Y, [Zz|Z]) :- % Case where Zz is not a divisor of Y.
    0 =\= Y mod Zz,
    modded(T, Y, Z).
```

Then

```
?- modded(X,16,[2,3,4,5,7,8]).
X = [2, 4, 8]
```

The base case holds for an empty list of input and output.

The middle case holds if Zz is a divisor and is added to the result list [Zz|T].

The last case holds if Zz is not a divisor and is not added to the result list T.

Both calculating cases recurse down the remaining Z list to fill in the remaining T of results.

---

If you weren't forced to use recursion, you might write:

```
modded(X, Y, Z) :-
    findall(Zz, (member(Zz, Z), 0 =:= Y mod Zz), X).
```

"Find all the Zzs which are members of Z and divisors of Y, and store them in X".

or

```
num_divisor(Y, Zz) :-
    0 =:= Y mod Zz.

modded(X, Y, Z) :-
    include(num_divisor(Y), Z, X).
```

---

Comments you may need to hear but likely won't care about:

If you are using SWI Prolog then https://swish.swi-prolog.org/ is a brilliant tool you can try bits of code instantly without the edit/saving/reload. Try putting some of your bits of code into it:

```
Z =:= []
Type error: `evaluable' expected, found `[]' (an empty_list)
```

That line is never going to work. Nor is the next line:

```
X =:= Z.
Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
In:
   [1] _1722=:=_1724
```

In the line `modded([Zz|T],Y,[H|T])` by using `T` in those to places, you're saying that the tail of both lists must be the same. One of those lists is the input, one is the filtered output. That can't work.

In the line `0 is Y mod Zz` it says Zz divides Y. Weren't the arguments to `modded` supposed to be (Result, Number, Input)? So with `modded([Zz|T],Y,[H|T])` wouldn't that be `H` dividing into Y, not `Zz` which has no value yet?

In the line `0 is Y mod Zz` it says Zz divides Y. But if it did work and the input got to `3` this line would be false, because 3 doesn't divide 16 evenly, so the whole program would fail. There's no handling for what to do if a number isn't a divisor.

The line `Y =< Z - 1` doesn't work like other languages either, `=<` will not calculate Z - 1. Which is almost lucky because Z has no value here in the code. (And even if it had, didn't you say it was the input list? What is Y =< [2,3,4,5,7,8] - 1 going to be?)

`Zz is Z + 1` Z also has no value here, but if it had it would fail because Zz is bound at the top with `modded([Zz` and it
`modded(T,Y,Zz)` wasn't the last argument of `modded` the input list, why is it now a divisor? And the first argument was the result, now it's the tail of the input list?

Yes you are confused, you need to get familiar with the basics before trying to build on them.

[Unification and proof search](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlch2)

[Recursing down lists](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//lpnpage.php?pagetype=html&pageid=lpn-htmlse15) at LearnPrologNow.